# add custom sheet in excel files using ssis

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I have created a SSIS package in which I have created dynamic excel files with 2 worksheets in each file. I want to add a 3rd worksheet into each excel file which consists of my custom page.

All the existing excel files are in a folder, and I am looking to loop through all the files in that folder and add the custom page as the 3rd worksheet of each file.

I am stuck in not getting the whole cover sheet itself with images. I can create a new work sheet within my excel files but it only exports the text from that cover sheet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am looking to create a new worksheet for each excel file with my cover sheet init. @TabAlleman

Comment: Saying what you want isn't the same as asking a question.   Where are you stuck?   Did you get an error?

Comment: Yes I am stuck in not getting the whole cover sheet itself with images. I can create a new work sheet within my excel files but it only exports the text from that cover sheet. @TabAlleman